# jquery creating tooltip

Tags: jquery

I want to create a tooltip, when user hovers over a link, it shows a tooltip, but does not close on mouseout. It closes only on tooltip area mouseout. In other words, I would be able to hover a link, see a tooltip, navigate to that tooltip with a mouse and do other events inside. Once I mouse out that tooltip (not a link), it closes out. I have a code which shows a tooltip on the link hover, but it hides it as soon as I try to move to that tooltip area. I am using simple live hover method:

```
 myLink.live('mouseover mouseout', function (e) { 
     ...show balloon...
 }
```

how do I make it close on tooltip mouse out, but not myLink mouseout? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    myLink.live('mouseover', function (e) { 
         //Code to show the tooltip
         $("toolTipContainerSelector").fadeIn(200);  
    });

$("toolTipContainerSelector").mouseout(function(){
       $(this).hide();
    })

//The below code will take care of hiding the tooltip if you click on the page other than the tooltip. In case you need this please use the below code
    $("body").click(function(){
       if($("toolTipContainerSelector").is(":visible"))
         $("toolTipContainerSelector").hide();
    });

    $("toolTipContainerSelector").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: in the fist method, where I display my mouseover effect, is it possible to add .fadeIn() or similar effects? how?

Answer (score 0):

Either use an [existing jQuery tooltip plugin](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/), or study one of those that you like to see how they handled it.  You'll need to deal with event bubbling and keeping track of which areas you want to handle `mouseovers` and `mouseouts` in.

Comment: I dont wanna use existing ones. I am interested in implementation, not tooltip itself

Answer (score 0):

Here is slightly different take on your question along with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SsAY5/3/